# Is there a better way to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` than an infinite loop with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

A program I am developing has a long running process in another thread. I would like to interrupt that thread in the event something goes awry.

Of other SO posts I've seen like this, they use syntax similar to this:

```py
while True:
    if condition_here:
        break
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

which does work in catching `KeyboardInterrupts`. However, I'm not a big fan of using while loops like this and would like to avoid this if at all possible.

For some example code, here is what I currently have (which does not catch the interrupts until after the thread is done):

```py
import asyncio
import time
from threading import Thread

def some_long_process():
    time.sleep(60)

async def main():
    thread = Thread(target=some_long_process)
    thread.start()

    # Doesn't work
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, thread.join)
    # await asyncio.wait([loop.run_in_executor(None, thread.join)])
    # await asyncio.wait_for(loop.run_in_executor(None, thread.join), None)
    # await asyncio.gather(asyncio.to_thread(thread.join))

    # Works
    # while thread.is_alive():
    #     await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I'm also open to suggestions to reconsider my entire approach to the way this is designed if this isn't possible. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a while loop+asycnio.sleep really is the simplest and best way to handle it. Fundamentally, what you want to do is have your main thread wait around from some termination event, and then use that to trigger killing the other process. Python can technically be made to function in an event driven way like this, but all the modules which do that are actually just spinning in a while loop in the background: might as well just run the loop yourself

Comment: @JonathanDBVanSchenck Okay, sounds good. I know that everything is running as a loop in the backend (hence "event loop" lol), so I was hoping to just utilize that instead of having my own loop run inside of it. Thanks.